# Is there any easy way to calculate the percentage change of a vector in rust?

Tags: vector, rust

Is there any easy way to calculate the percentage change of a vector in rust?

Or do I just loop through the values with a for-loop?

```rust
let vec1 = vec![90.0, 91.0, 85.0];

let pct_change = vec1.pct_change()
```

Expected output:

```
[NaN, 0.011111, -0.065934]
```

Comment: Percentage change between the current and a prior element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) slice method to iterate over 2-element subslices of the vector:

```
let pct_change = vec1
    .windows(2)
    .map(|w| (w[1] - w[0]) / w[0])
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12771ccb36f5c227c8af1606a5784ec9)

Another possibility, which will work on any iterable, is [`tuple_windows()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) provided by the `itertools` crate:

```
let pct_change = vec1
    .iter()
    .tuple_windows()
    .map(|(a, b)| (b - a) / a)
    .collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d18bb2cd279c8f0e255ec7af92db27de)